# Value of other keys in an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that stores the name of the countries in Persian and English, like this:

```
$countries = array(
    array("id"=>1,"fa"=>"اتریش","en"=>"Austria"),
    array("id"=>2,"fa"=>"اتیوپی","en"=>"Ethiopia"),
    array("id"=>3,"fa"=>"اردن","en"=>"Jordan")
);
```

I want to have the Persian version of a country using the English one. For example:

```
$Eng = 'Jordan';
$Fa = requiredFunction($Eng);
echo $Fa;
//output should be: اردن
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @MForMarlon I can do it in a loop. I kinda was hopeful there's a shorter way. :)